# transition between UIViewController from navigation drawer

Tags: ios, swift3, cosmicmind

I am Using Swift 3. I have searched about this and found the solution

```
navigationDrawerController?.TransitionFromRootViewController
```

but when I used this line it say `TransitionFromRootViewController` is not a function.

So I tried Using

```
navigationDrawerController?.transition(from: RootViewController(), to: destViewController(), duration: 0.2, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil, completion: nil)
```

but it shows error that the:

> "child view controller must have a common parent view controller when calling transitionfrom view controller"

Can anyone help me please? If someone can push an example of navigation drawer with the switching would be a great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, which I posted to the [NavigationDrawerController example project](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/tree/master/Examples/Programmatic/NavigationDrawerController) in the programmatic directory, Material [2.1.2](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/releases/tag/2.1.2).

It shows how to transition with multiple  navigation controllers, and by itself.

```
import UIKit
import Material

class LeftViewController: UIViewController {
private var transitionButton: FlatButton!

open override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = Color.blue.base

    prepareTransitionButton()
}

@objc
internal func handleTransitionButton() {
    // Transition the entire NavigationDrawer rootViewController.
    // navigationDrawerController?.transition(to: TransitionedViewController(), completion: closeNavigationDrawer)

    // Transition the ToolbarController rootViewController that is in the 
    // NavigationDrawer rootViewController.
    (navigationDrawerController?.rootViewController as? ToolbarController)?.transition(to: TransitionedViewController(), completion: closeNavigationDrawer)
}

internal func closeNavigationDrawer(result: Bool) {
    navigationDrawerController?.closeLeftView()
}

private func prepareTransitionButton() {
    transitionButton = FlatButton(title: "Transition VC", titleColor: Color.white)
    transitionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTransitionButton), for: .touchUpInside)

    view.layout(transitionButton).horizontally().center()
}
}
```

You can find a reference to the discussion in [GitHub issue-546](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/issues/546)

All the best!

Comment: Thanks for everything

Comment: if  i am using toolbar controller then it is working but if  i am using Navigation controller in place of toolbar controller then it is not working

Comment: when i edited the example project and used navigation controller in that then the app is crashed with the message "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Parent view controller is using legacy containment in call to -[UIViewController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:]'
"

Comment: For the navigation controller you would use the normal `push` API. Sorry, that is the only exception.

Comment: is it possible to set the height of toolBar?

Comment: I am working on a way to do so that is easy with the controllers.

Comment: @Ayushsharma I have a solution for doing this :) Posting a new version. Also, in general, it is better to keep a conversation like this in Gitter, as the Stack question pertains to another question.

Comment: Did you post the new version?

Comment: Reworking a component to update against your request. Your question pushed me to make a really cool solution for setting the height of all `Bar` type components. Shouldn't be much longer. The `development` branch currently has the solution in their you are seeking.